# zsh !! and !$ auto execute as it does in bash

Tags: zsh, command-history

I recently made the switch from bash to zsh. I discovered two minuscule issues and differences between zsh and bash. I was slightly disappointed when my favorite two shortcuts `!!` & `!$` don't behave as they do in bash.

When I try to the following with the argument shortcuts (sorry I don't know what they're formally called) they would automatically execute like the following in bash:

```
$ touch foo
$ vim !$
<file opens immediately>
```

While in zsh they become translated then executed (I have to hit enter one extra time):

```
$ touch foo
$ vim !$
$ vim foo
```

Is there a way to have `!$` & `!!`, in zsh, behave the same way as it does in bash?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From `man zshoptions`

```
HIST_VERIFY
    Whenever the user enters a line with history expansion,  don't  execute  the  line
    directly;  instead, perform history expansion and reload the line into the editing buffer.
```

To disable this option run `setopt no_hist_verify`. You can also have a look at your config file and remove the hist_verify option or just explicitly disable it.